# Using inequalities in T distributions

Tags: probability

I am trying to work out the value of a random variable T defined as follows: T is from a Student-$t$ distribution with degrees of freedom $7$.

Find $t$ such that $$P(T> -t )+ P(T > 0 )+ P(T > t)+ P(T> 2t) = 1.75$$

I still think the answer lies in the symmetrical nature of this distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The distribution is symmetric and continuous so that.

- $P(T>0)+P(T<0)=1$ and $P(T>0)=P(T<0)$ hence $P(T>0)=0.50$.
- $P(T>-t)=1-P(T<-t)=1-P(T>t)$.

This together simplifies the question: find $t$ such that $P(T>2t)=0.25$.